# Embedding a R - Leaflet map on a jekyll site hosted on Github

Tags: r, leaflet, jekyll, github-pages

I have a website [here](http://apapiu.github.io) hosted on Github Pages using Beautiful Jekyll. See [here](https://github.com/apapiu/apapiu.github.io) for the actual code behind the blog on Github.

I'd like to embed a leaflet map into one of my blog posts. I am using the R package leaflet.

So say for example I make a map:

```
library(htmlwidgets)
library(leaflet)

m <- leaflet() %>% #basic map
     addTiles() %>%
```

How do I embed this on my page? One thing I tried to do is save the html file using:

```
saveWidget(widget = m, file="your_map.html", selfcontained = FALSE)
```

This works and saves the html file locally. I tried copying and pasting the html code into one of `_posts` on Github but that didn't work. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at how they are doing this for the [official R leaflet page](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet) at [their github page](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/tree/gh-pages) (the one for the website, not for the leaflet-code).

I don't see on your site that you are using R-markdown to create your markdown pages. It is really worth a try! Have a look at [yihui's jekyll example](http://yihui.name/knitr-jekyll/2014/09/jekyll-with-knitr.html). Basically you use [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) to generate your pages. This means you write markdown and are able to embed your R-Code into the markdown page. Like for example:

````
```{r}
plot(runif(10))
```
````

The same you can do with leaflet:

````
```{r}
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(10, 51, zoom = 8)
```
````

`htmlwidgets` should be automatically loaded by knitr.

For example you can have a look how the [basemap page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/leaflet/gh-pages/basemaps.Rmd) for the R leaflet page is done in R-markdown.

One important thing if you include leaflet maps in your page is though to include all the scripts in the page head. On my page I inserted it in the `head.html` in the `_includes` folder.

I had to add the following:

```
{% if page.maps %}
<script src="/assets/jquery-1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-3.3.1/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-3.3.1/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/htmlwidgets-0.5/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="/assets/leafletfix-1.0.0/leafletfix.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/leaflet-binding-1.0.1/leaflet.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

I added an option `maps: true` into the front matter of pages with maps so that the part `{% if page.maps %}` makes sure that all this code is only loaded for pages that need it.

I copied all the scripts from a folder that was created by knitr when I compiled the R-markdown page without jekyll. Therefore I had to set

```
output: 
  html_document: 
    self_contained: no
```

in the front matter (otherwise the code is embedded in the page and can't be copied so easily).

The team behind R leaflet include the libs in their [index.html](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/gh-pages/index.html) like this:

```
<script src="libs/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="libs/bootstrap/css/flatly.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/htmlwidgets/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<link href="libs/leaflet/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="libs/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="libs/leafletfix/leafletfix.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="libs/leaflet-binding/leaflet.js"></script>
```

You can copy the libs from [their libs folder](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/tree/gh-pages/libs).

I see on your page that you already got it to work with a different method. I just wanted to include this because I was just working on the same topic...

Comment: Oh I see that's pretty cool, thanks! what I did was publish the map to Rpubs then look at the html code there and copy the iframe with the map and paste it into my post. It's a little roundabouty but it works.  And I do have a way of posting rmarkdown but the way you suggested seems better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @nnn answer I put together a tutorial for doing so:

[FULL TUTORIAL ON THIS LINK](https://dieghernan.github.io/201905_Leaflet_R_Jekyll/#step1)

In short:

**On GitHub/Jekyll**

1. Identify the code you need to include. I already did it for you [See on my GitHub](https://github.com/dieghernan/dieghernan.github.io/blob/master/_includes/leaflet.html)
2. Copy/paste it in the code that builds your `<head>`. This would depend on your Jekyll implementation. After doing that, the needed libraries would be loaded every time that Jekyll builds the website.

**On Rstudio**

3. Create a map with `leaflet` and knit it to a `github_document`. It is important to knit  it using `always_allow_html: yes` in the front matter.

**On Markdown**

4. Check that every `leaflet`map has produced an `html` code in the `.md`file. Something like this:

```html
<!--html_preserve-->

  <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER">
    {"x":{"options": ...
<!--more funky code here-->
```

5. Paste this chunk before the `<script>` part:

```html
<div id="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER" style="width:100%;height:216px;" class="leaflet html-widget"></div>
```

So you got something like this for each `leaflet` map:

```html
<!--html_preserve-->
 <div id="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER" style="width:100%;height:216px;" class="leaflet html- widget"></div>

  <script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-SOMEIDNUMBER">
    {"x":{"options": ...
<!--more funky code here-->
```

Now publish it on GitHub. Now when **Jekyll** builds your blog/web hosted on **GitHub** the libraries are loaded and the leaflet map displays correctly. Note that on local or markdown the map is still not visible.

Once that you have done it a couple of times you will see that is basicaly copy/paste/modify the chunk that I presented on step 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here https://jayrobwilliams.com/posts/2020/09/jekyll-html

Store the output from the `saveWidget` in your website directory.

wrap the relative path in an iframe and style as you please.

```
<iframe src="/interactiveDocs/map.html" height="600px" width="100%" style="border:none;"></iframe>
```

It has worked well for my purposes